# сдвиг элементов массива

Tags: c++, массивы, arduino

Задача следующая:
есть пиктограммы отображающие определенный процесс на экране (5 пиктограмм):

[....{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}] - это все пиктограммы когда все процессы активны
[....{1}{.}{3}{.}{5}] - это когда процессы 2 и 4 не активны

Так то проблем нет, но на экране смотрится нелаконично.

Как сделать так:

[....{.}{.}{1}{3}{5}]

а при активации процесса 2

[....{.}{2}{1}{3}{5}]

чтобы он просто занял пустое не занятое место.

Проект на *Ардуино*.

Comment: Если процесс добавляется то вставлять его в первое пустое место. Если процесс удаляется сдвигать все процессы после него на 1 элемент, последний элемент выставлять пустым или на его место ставить последний процесс из списка.

Comment: так в моем вопросе это и описано , что все должны сдвигаться и закрывать собой освободившиеся места, но как это сделать в коде, я понимаю , что копать надо в сторону массивов , но и на этом мое понимание заканчивается

Comment: я примерно представляю так 5 функций (пиктограмм bool fn_1(int x1, bool status) .... bool fn_5(int x5, bool status) принимают координаты по икс и возвращают статус ) над ними функция проверяющая статусы всех функций и те у которых возвратилась 1 , выставляет в определенном порядке и если в ряде функций сменился статус она сдвинула остальные!

Comment: покажите ваш текущий код для начала

Comment: так в коде пока нет даже упоминания этой функции т.к. она еще не проработана и только в мыслях

Comment: прошу помощи у @BuilderC

Comment: А что вас останавливает от самостоятельного написания функции? Вы не знаете как работать с массивами на C? Вы не знаете как использовать цикл for на C?

Comment: массивы знаю, цикл тоже , а вот применить не соображаю как ... для этого я и обратился к сообществу !! если бы меня не останавливало мое незнание от самостоятельного написания функции , то я бы тут с вами не дискутировал по наводящим вопросам....тыкать носом в букварь указывая на буквы и при этом говорить: "что ты стихи то сочинить не можешь , что букв не знаешь?" я довольно развернуто ответил на ваш столь проницательный вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
void showInactive() {
  for (int n = 0; n < 5: ++n)
     if (procInactive(n))
        showInactiveProc(n);
}

void showActive() {
  for (int n = 0; n < 5: ++n)
     if (procActive(n))
        showActiveProc(n);
}

void showProcesses() {
  showInactive();
  showActive();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! это как я понимаю мы опрашиваем и разделяем на два типа активных и не активных ! а вот теперь как неактивные скрыть с экрана, оставив только активные и сгруппировав их вместе (без пробелов)?

Comment: Просто не показывайте их, и всё.

Comment: @ТимурМирхайдаров Вы б отметили комент человека как 'решение вопроса' - лучшее "спасибо" =)